# Como adicionar texto em posição especifica em Array de Strings

Tags: ios, swift

**Cenário:**

Tenho um webservice que utilizo para pegar textos, estes textos podem ser modificados por uma interface web, mas o titulo
deles sempre será fixo, por isto foi decidido a inserção deles diretamente na aplicação mobile.

**O que estou fazendo atualmente:**

Estou realizando uma requisição que transforma esse json em um array de Strings.
Depois de fazer o loop e criar este Array Com Strings carrego uma tabela.

Agora, preciso redefinir este Array utilizando outro array fixo com a Seguinte Estrutura.

```
let textoFixo:[String] = ["Titulo 1", "Leia mais", "Titulo 2","Leia mais","Titulo 3"]
```

Sendo o Array da requisição:

```
let texto:[String] = ["conteudo1","conteudo2","conteudo3"];
```

Se tornando assim:

```
let texto:[String] = ["Titulo 1","conteudo1","Leia mais","Titulo 2","conteudo2","Leia mais"]
```

Sendo que o Titulo deve ter fonte maior em negrito  e o leia mais deve ser direcionado para outra tela, que será estatica também podendo ser acionada por um pushViewController:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

**Implementação:**

```
import UIKit
import MMDrawerController
import SwiftyJSON


class FooViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource  {
    var texto = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let load = Loader(view: self.view) // progress loader
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

        let api = API() 
        api.get("foo") { responseObject, error in // request json data

            let value = JSON(responseObject!)

            for (_, subJson) in post {  // fill array of strings
                self.texto.append(subJson.stringValue)
            }

            self.table!.reloadData() // load de table with the data
            load.stop(self.view)
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.texto.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Pode ocorrer da estrutura ser quebrada se existir dois conteudos sendo cada um deles um paragrafo.

Comment: Olha isso pra ver se eh o que vc quer e te ajuda... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028860/how-to-find-index-of-list-item-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método insert passando como segundo parâmetro a posição do array a ser inserida.

**Exemplo:**

```
texto.insert(textoFixo[0], atIndex: 0);
texto.insert(textoFixo[1], atIndex: 2);
```